# Insert a circle into a map dynamically in d3.js using county Id

Tags: javascript, sockets, d3.js

I am trying to insert a circle into a element on the map/HTML page at the centroid

```
function socket() {
    socket.on = io.('/map');
    socket.on(func(data)) {
    var countyid = data.countyid;
    var isAffected = data.affected; //may be 0 or 1
    var selectorId = '[id="'+ Number(countyid)+'"]';
    svg.selectAll(selectorId)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class","circle")
        .attr('transform', path.centroid(d3.select(countyid)))
        .attr('r',20);
    }
}
```

It seems to not work correctly.

I have been able to solve this using a very different approach.

I created the centroid for all the counties using https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/

Then I changed attributes of the centroids using jquery.
In this manner I removed the svg creation through a socket.

Comment: the code should break even before trying to draw any circles - check the JS

Comment: This is definitely closer to a pseudocode concept. Not the actual runnable code.

Comment: @NemoK You can set the position of the circles without `cx` or `cy`, using only `transform` (so, ignore the two answers below), but you have to `return` a "translate" value, correctly retrieving the indices of the `centroid` array. Thus, to help you with *"why is this code not working?"*, you have to provide the actual code, not a pseudocode.

Answer (score -1):

To draw circle in svg can be achieved by specifying its attributes.

- **cx,cy,r**

**cx,cy** determine the position for the circle to draw inside svg. Basically X axis and Y axis oriented position

**r** is the radius of the circle

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
</svg>
```

*Specify the attribute in your code and that will work out for you*

Comment: May i know the issue of this answer?